# How can I display an event’s time alone (without the title) on a jQuery FullCalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am wondering if it's possible to just show the time reserved on the calendar, not the title of the event, using jQuery’s [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) plug-in?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "time reserved" and "want to show on the calender" -- where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere along the lines of 3665 inside the fullCalendaer normal version look for this code

```
(!event.allDay && seg.isStart ?
"<span class='fc-event-time'>" +
htmlEscape(formatDates(event.start, event.end, opt('timeFormat'))) +
"</span>"
:'') +
"<span class='fc-event-title'>" + htmlEscape(event.title) + "</span>" +
```

Remove

```
"<span class='fc-event-title'>" + htmlEscape(event.title) + "</span>" +
```

So that it still makes sense i jscript syntax and viola! no  more title just time.

Comment: Yes this will work, but now everytime you upgrade fullcalendar you have to remember to remove this line.  Better to just hide it as @Doomsday suggested.

Comment: Yes- but if he wanted to customize it even further(at a higher and more efficient level)- he knows where to start. jQuery is the easiest though, i agree.

Comment: Thank you! It does work! If you don't mind i have one more question: i'm writing an asp.net mvc room reservation app where i'm trying to integrate the fullcalendar. so when someone reserves a room for an event, they choose a time for the event, give it a title, and the system assigns a reservation ID for the event. Then on the dayslot of the calendar we see the time reserved for the event and the title of this event. So I'd like to display a reservation ID instead of the title of the event. Is it possible? Thank you so much!

Comment: Yea I could. but I just done feel like it since I do not even get any votes or points.. for good constructive information, which was correct in the first place.. sorry man- maybe later when i am really bored.

Comment: @ppumkin:  All I was saying that if it's just this that you wanted to change, it's better to just manipulate it with css.  Don't get me wrong, I took the fullcalendar source and extensively modified it to get it to do with what I wanted.  It just made upgrades a pain, which is all I wanted to point out.  I upvote you, as this is a valid solution under the right circumstances.

Comment: @ppumkin: I used your tip on how to remove a title from a calendar leaving just a time reserved. it worked fine. Would you please advise how to display another filed (like, a request ID, for example) next to the time on a dayslot of the calendar. I tried a few tips, but they don't really work as I need. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yea - sure - Ill check on Monday and play with the code and let you know ok. Today im having a beer ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can do everything you want with altering CSS class :

To hide event title:

```
.fc-event-time {
  display: none;
}
```

If you want to keep time of events but keep the same background between title and body, you should unset opacity:

```
.fc-event-vert .fc-event-bg {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response!

Comment: Sorry, there is something wrong with the comment box. I just wanted to ask you, if i have these lines in my fc.css: .fc-event-time,
.fc-event-title {
 padding: 0 1px;
 } and as you recommended, i deleted the '.fc-event-title' line and put the 'display: none;' instead, I still have the title of the event on the day slot of the calendar displayed. Am I doing something wrong here? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: In the day slot of the calendar, all events title are shown. What did you except exactly? If you want to hide dayslot, you have to set FullCalendar option "allDaySlot: false"

Comment: i don't want to hide dayslot. What i would like to do is just to show the time reserved on a dayslot of the calendar, not the title of the event. Instead of the title of event, I would like the reservation ID # displayed. Is it possible? thank you everyone helping me!

Comment: AllDaySlot is here to display only events with a duration > 1 day (all day long). You talk about reservation ID but what is it exactly ? Which reservation system are you using ?

Comment: i'm writing an asp.net mvc room reservation app where i'm trying to integrate the fullcalendar. when someone reserves a room for an event, they choose a time for the event, give it a title, and the system assigns a reservation ID for the event. Then on the dayslot of the calendar we see the time reserved for the event and the title of this event. So I'd like to display a reservation ID instead of the title of the event. Does it make any sense? Thanks a lot for helping me!

Comment: Look the event's creation at demos/ of FullCalendar. You can assign everything you want into the title of event. You should set reservation ID into title of the event.

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't find a demos page of FullCalendar. It was a while ago when I asked  a question about how to display another field instead of the event title on the dayslot of the calendar. I'd like to have a time reserved and a reservation ID next to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With this, install the module Auto Entity Labels or Auto Nodetitles and when you go and edit the Content Type created, you'll see tabs such as "Edit", "Manage Fields", "Auto Label", etc...

When you click on "Auto Label', set the Automatic Label Generation to "Automatically generate the label and hide the label field" and set the Pattern for the title to `<none>`.

Now when you create content from the content type, i.e. FullCalendar, it will just show the timeslot you've entered without the title of the node.